# iOS Crash - terminate from FrontBoardServices

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, crash

I'm getting a stacktrace that I have been having a difficult time tracking down the source.  It happens in production and we have not been able to reproduce locally.

```
Incident Identifier: *
Hardware Model:      iPad11,4
Process:             MyApp [900]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/27DCC9B7-76AF-491F-9804-7F7B45FC2FB9/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier:          com.mycompany.myapp
Version:             3 (1.0.0)
AppStoreTools:       12E506
AppVariant:          1:iPad11,4:14
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Non UI
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.mycompany.myapp [402]


Date/Time:           2021-08-05 13:03:33.7235 +0200
Launch Time:         2021-08-05 12:42:41.7888 +0200
OS Version:          iPhone OS 14.6 (18F72)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    3.04.01
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001c1577334 0x1c154e000 + 168756
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001dea41a9c pthread_kill + 272 (pthread.c:1582)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000019cea9c10 __abort + 116 (abort.c:147)
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000019cea9b9c abort + 116 (abort.c:118)
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a86a3bb8 abort_message + 132 (abort_message.cpp:78)
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a86a2fc0 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 52 (cxa_handlers.cpp:67)
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a86a2f2c std::terminate() + 48 (cxa_handlers.cpp:88)
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001936e8830 _dispatch_client_callout + 40 (object.m:562)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001936ec30c _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 268 (queue.c:468)
9   FrontBoardServices              0x00000001a30e0fa0 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 48 (FBSSerialQueue.m:184)
10  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001a30e0c30 -[FBSSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 448 (FBSSerialQueue.m:227)
11  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001a30e1184 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 32 (FBSSerialQueue.m:258)
12  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000193a759e8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28 (CFRunLoop.c:1967)
13  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000193a758e4 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 208 (CFRunLoop.c:2011)
14  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000193a74be8 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 268 (CFRunLoop.c:2048)
15  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000193a6ebc8 __CFRunLoopRun + 820 (CFRunLoop.c:2925)
16  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000193a6e360 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3242)
17  GraphicsServices                0x00000001ab0ac734 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2259)
18  UIKitCore                       0x00000001964e9584 -[UIApplication _run] + 1072 (UIApplication.m:3269)
19  UIKitCore                       0x00000001964eedf4 UIApplicationMain + 168 (UIApplication.m:4740)
20  MyApp                           0x0000000104aed5e0 main + 76 (main.m:38)
21  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019372acf8 start + 4
```

What is the cause of a crash like this?  What is the best way to debug a crash like this?

Answer (score 1):

From apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/understanding-the-exception-types-in-a-crash-report):

> EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) 
> EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) indicates the process terminated because it received the SIGABRT signal. Typically, this signal is sent because a function in the process called abort(), such as when an app encounters an uncaught Objective-C or C++ language exception. Addressing Language Exception Crashes explains how to handle uncaught language exceptions in more detail. 
> If there isn’t a Last Exception Backtrace indicating a langauge exception triggered the crash, look at the crashed thread’s backtrace to determine if code in the process called abort().
> When an app extension takes too much time to initialize, the operating system sends a SIGABRT to the app extension process. These crashes include an Exception Subtype field with the value LAUNCH_HANG. Because extensions don’t have a main function, any time spent initializing occurs within static constructors and load() methods present in your extension and dependent libraries. Although the exception information is different in a watchdog termination, investigate the LAUNCH_HANG with the same techniques discussed in Addressing Watchdog Terminations.

It seems the process called abort even before a call from FrontBoardServices.

Have a look at this [Help with crash log EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/19859) This might help!

Comment: "The process called abort even before a call from FrontBoardServices" - Can you elaborate on this?  Which process called abort?  Should I be looking at other processes/threads in the stack trace?  What is FrontBoardServices?  Does this indicate the app is launching or waking up from being minimized?  Thanks for any clarification.  Your link seems to forward to a discussion resulting in insertObject being called incorrectly, but my stack trace doesn't have my own code involved?  Thanks.

Comment: FrontBoardServices is nothing but the client framework to the FrontBoard system of iOS. In simple terms it is a private framework used by UIKit. I might have a guess at what's going on if you upload the complete crash log. Meanwhile I have the impression that one or more of your xib files or storyboards contain an element which is no longer available in the versions of iOS the device is on. This could explain why you can't reproduce it locally.

Comment: The app is a cordova app, so I would be skeptical that it's nib/storyboard related.  Stats from crashlytics do indicate that this is happening 96% in the background.  Would there be a specific part of the crash report you would be interested in?

Comment: The entire Crash Report would be the best, but minimally if you can give the `Last Exception Backtrace:` it would point out to something. If there might be sensitive/ confidential information in there you can hide it using Asterisks.

Comment: I've included more information in the original post from the report, the entire top section of the report as well as the main thread's crash.  I'm not seeing any `Last Exception Backtrace` anywhere in the report?  Any help in finding that is appreciated.

Comment: There is no specific information in this entire crashlog which would point out to what caused it to call abort. If you don't have to immediately fix the issue fill your app with NSLog wherever you suspect the crash might have occurred from and create a new release. If still you have no help you need to file a bug report to Apple.

Comment: We've identified one of potentially multiple crashes that contribute to this crash report in firebase.  We have a background task that, when it expires, we create some NSURLSession uploads.  When constructing the URL object from the string, the URL.init method was causing a crash due to an invalid string.